# What should be considered when moving temporarily to Saudi Arabia

Tags: culture, saudi-arabia

How should an EU-citizen prepare for a temporary internship in Saudi Arabia given that they are not acquainted to the (I presume vastly) different culture and bureaucracy. Is there a reliable and informative general resource where they can familiarize themself with the culture?

**Note: Mekka / Thuwal area**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be fine, in fact, you will be amazed that everything you hear on TV is basically wrong when it comes to Saudi Arabia. People are friendly and you will run into many Europeans and in no time you will have friends over here, both locals and Europeans.

Saudi is a big country and depending on where you are planning to go, it might be really cold or hot, so check the weather and be ready for that.

Regarding government paperwork, almost everything is electronic, this includes opening a bank account and so.

English will be more than enough for you. Almost everyone speaks it to a different degree.

It will be a good experience, try to enjoy it.

Source: I am a Saudi, who has a lot of European colleagues and friends.

Comment: It might be noted that the region is Thuwal.

Comment: Could you give more advise here?

Comment: @stephanmg Thuwal? I assue it will be KAUST?

Comment: @stephanmg It is a small town, the beach is minutes away and that's a big plus, Jeddah which is the second-largest city in Saudi is like an hour away by car. KAUST is quite a nice work and living place and is full of westerners.

Comment: You can say something about the typical living expenses?

Comment: @stephanmg It is mostly cheaper than Europe, there's a 15% VAT. You will do fine.